# Converting (char*)variable to int

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, data-type

I have the following code:

```
      uint8_t buf[1];
      uint8_t buflen = 1;
      if (driver.recv(buf, &buflen)) // Non-blocking
         {
            int i;
            // Message with a good checksum received, dump it.
            Serial.print("Message: ");
            Serial.println((char*)buf);//this prints out okay
            highPins[(char*)buf] = 1;
         }
```

The problem is in highPins[(char*)buf]. highPins is array, and in (char*)buf I get index number. When I display it with Serial.println, it shows the number, but here it does not. I am guessing its because (char*)buf is not a number. I have tried to convert it to int with few functions I have found online, but it was unsuccessful. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: `String(buf).toInt()` is how i do it, but there might be better ways...

Comment: `highPins[buf[0] - '0'] = 1;` should do the trick :)

Comment: Note that `Serial.println(const char[])` expects a NUL-terminated buffer. It will read your memory starting at `&buf` and continue until it finds a NUL byte.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest improving your code slightly as follows:

```
  uint8_t buf;
  uint8_t buflen = 1;
  if (driver.recv(&buf, &buflen)) // Non-blocking
     {
        int i;
        // Message with a good checksum received, dump it.
        Serial.print("Message: ");
        Serial.println(buf);//this prints out okay
        highPins[buf] = 1;
     }
```

The important point is that you do not need to declare `buf` as an array of just one element, but just declare the element itself (as `uint8_t`) and pass its address (`&buf`) to `driver.recv(...)`.

As @Majenko suggested, you should alos check `buf` before using it as an index to `highPins` array, in order to avoid using an index bigger than teh array size.

Comment: The thing is, when I use your code, I get a strange result. I send string 33 with `driver.send("33",  sizeof("33"));
      `, and with your code I get "53" over the serial. Any idea on what might be causing it?

Comment: You have to know what gets transferred between both devices: is that string or numbers? Your question made me think this was numbers (in binary representation, not as ASCII strings). You probably need to provide more details in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The function you want is `atoi`.

```
int pinno = atoi((char *)buf);
```

I would suggest checking that the result is in the right range before using it.